# How to check if some word separated by an arbitration character are present in another string without considering their order

Tags: javascript

I need to check if all keys on string `a` are present in string `b` (a key is for example CTRL).

Keys are always separated by "-".

I need the comparison return true does not matter the order of keys in b. Keys cannot be duplicated in a string ex `CTRL-SHIFT-CTRL-C` returns false.

```
var a = 'CTRL-SHIFT-C';  
var b = 'CTRL-SHIFT-C';
```

Example comparison result:

```
var a = 'CTRL-SHIFT-C';  
var b = 'C-SHIFT-CTRL'; // true

var a = 'CTRL-SHIFT-C';  
var b = 'SHIFT-C-CTRL'; // true

var a = 'CTRL-SHIFT-C';  
var b = 'CTRL-SHIFT-C-D'; // false
```

Currently I am using this code, but in some case does not work properly.

```js
var a = 'CTRL-SHIFT-A'; // does no work
                var b = 'SHIFT-A';

                var aPart = a.split('-');
                var bPart = b.split('-');
                var intersection = aPart.filter(function (n) {
                    return bPart.indexOf(n) != -1;
                });

                if (intersection.length !== bPart.length) {
                    alert('different keys');
                } else {
                    alert('same keys');
                }
```

Comment: Should `CTRL-A` match `ctrl-a`?

Comment: @Cerbrus no, it is not required, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should cover it:

```js
var a = 'CTRL-SHIFT-C';  
var b = 'C-SHIFT-CTRL';

function compareStrings(a, b){
  if(a === b)  // Same strings
    return true
  if(!a || !b || a.length !== b.length) // Strings are falsy or don't have the same length.
    return false

  var splitA = a.split('-').sort(), // Sort the keys
      splitB = b.split('-').sort();
  
  if(splitA.length !== splitB.length) // Unequal amount of keys > false
    return false
  
  for(var i = 0; i < splitA.length; i++){
    if(splitA[i] !== splitB[i] ||          // Keys mismatch > false
      (i > 0 && splitA[i] == splitA[i-1])) // Duplicate keys > false
      return false; // (You don't have to check b for duplicates, since b has to match a)
  }
  return true; // All is good, the strings match. > true
}

alert(compareStrings(a, b))
```

Sure, it's a little longer than the `every` method, but it's thorough, including null checks. The only thing that's kinda missing is to check if the provided parameters are in fact strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
function compare(s1, s2) {
    s1 = s1.split('-');
    s2 = s2.split('-');
    return (s1.length === s2.length) && (s1.every(function (elem) {
         return (s2.indexOf(elem) !== -1);
    }));
}

var a = 'CTRL-SHIFT-C';  
var b = 'C-SHIFT-CTRL'; // true

console.log(compare(a, b));

a = 'CTRL-SHIFT-C';  
b = 'SHIFT-C-CTRL'; // true

console.log(compare(a, b));

a = 'CTRL-SHIFT-C';  
b = 'CTRL-SHIFT-C-D'; // false

console.log(compare(a, b));
```

You can check the documentation for Array.prototype.every method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

Comment: `compare('a-b-c-b','c-b-a-c')` returns `true`. This function doesn't validate if the same keys are entered twice, and if so, which. I'm not sure if that's a real problem, though ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus good point, I did not notice it, yes, the script should return false if a duplicate string is present

Comment: @GibboK: So, `compare('a-a', 'a-a')` should return `false`?

Comment: @GibboK: I've added something to my answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus :) I think your script cover all my scenarios. Thanks you all guys for your help on this.

Answer (score -2):

```
var regex = new RegExp('[' + a.replace(/-/g, '|') + '|-]', 'g');
var matches = b.match(regex).length === a.length;
```

Pure regex, doesn't get any better :-)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but if you have  var a = 'CTRL-SHIFT-C'; var b = 'CTRL-SHIFT'; it returns TRUE, instead should return FALSE.

Comment: @GibboK: I was just about to say the same :P

Comment: My bad, that is indeed correct. It's a simple fix, though. I have edited my first post.